# C# Extension (OmniSharp) gives false results in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm facing some issues using the C# Extension in VSCode. I'm having a basic project set up with one dependency and a Hello World writeline. When I run `dotnet run`, the project compiles and runs without issue. However, the C# Extension gives me 27 compile problems, all related to System classes. An example is:

```
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported (CS0518)
```

...even though System is marked as an `Unnecessary using directive. (CS8019)`.
There seems to be a discrepancy between the information `dotnet` and the extension are giving me. There have been similar issues before which suggest updating VSCode or the extension. That doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

I already tried it without the dependency, that doesn't change anything. It is interesting that I keep getting the message from VSCode that there is an unresolved dependency and I need to "restore". `dotnet restore` doesn't fix it though.

Example of false problems:

[image: False problems]

Project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
      <RootNamespace>project</RootNamespace>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Hashgraph" Version="3.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Version of different components:

```
> dotnet --version
3.0.100
> mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 6.4.0.198 (tarball Wed Sep 25 00:24:09 BST 2019)
> msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.85+gad9c9926a7
```

Edit: I'm on MacOS by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The C# 1.21.3 extension doesn't appear to be compatible with dotnet core 3.0.100.

My Fix:

I installed dotnet core 2.2 and added a global.json file to the project at the same level as the .csproj file.

Then added this json snippet inside the global.json:

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "2.2.402"
    }
}
```

Then I ran:

```
dotnet restore, 
dotnet clean, 
dotnet build
```

I guess we will have to wait for a fix to the extension for dotnet core 3

**Update:**
I read on another post the removing previously installed dotnet SDKs would fix the issue. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, I had 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0 installed. I removed 2.1 and 2.2   Now the extension is working with 3.0

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I had previous versions installed before but removed them. That didn't seem to fix the issue, maybe I should try to remove all dotnet versions and the extension and reinstall as a last ditch effort. For now I'll use Visual Studio (regular) which works without any issues!